# jquery star rating vertical

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the jquery star rating plugin by fyneworks. The problem is that about 5% of the time (and on the initial page load), the stars stack vertically instead of horizontally!?

When you refresh the page, they are fine - which is really odd. [Please see the page here.](http://www.nacremedia.com/stars/stars.html)

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

EDIT: [The unpacked JS can be found here](http://jquery-star-rating-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.rating.js)

Comment: try to switch the loading sequence of css and js

Comment: I've tried 'defer' on both the CSS and JS but to no avail :(

Comment: Working with that plugin drove me nuts. It appears to have been hacked on by like 8 different people. You know what I really hate? `//}; //save a byte!`. Seriously, get rid of braces to 'save a byte'? And then leave a comment about it?

Comment: Do you have any ideas about the above? :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this myself by using a different script from here instead:

http://orkans-tmp.22web.net/star_rating/

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Damn, this does the same after a few reloads. Well, this means that the javascript snippet - and/or built in javascript engine - fail. Try another star plugin, this one looks overbloated... 13K in size :O.

Here, you go, redone the whole thing, this works for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src='http://jquery-star-rating-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.js' type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src='http://jquery-star-rating-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.rating.js' type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script> 
<script src='http://jquery-star-rating-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.MetaData.js' type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script> 
<link href='http://jquery-star-rating-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.rating.css' type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>

<body>

<div class="Clear"> 
<input name="star1" type="radio" class="star {split:2}" value="0.5/5"/> 
<input name="star1" type="radio" class="star {split:2}" value="1/5"/> 
<input name="star1" type="radio" class="star {split:2}" value="1.5/5"/> 
<input name="star1" type="radio" class="star {split:2}" value="2/5"/> 
<input name="star1" type="radio" class="star {split:2}" value="2.5/5"/> 
<input name="star1" type="radio" class="star {split:2}" value="3/5" checked="checked"/> 
<input name="star1" type="radio" class="star {split:2}" value="3.5/5"/> 
<input name="star1" type="radio" class="star {split:2}" value="4/5"/> 
<input name="star1" type="radio" class="star {split:2}" value="4.5/5"/> 
<input name="star1" type="radio" class="star {split:2}" value="5/5"/> 
</div> 
<button class="rate" type="submit" title="Submit your rating">Rate!</button> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using firebug on your test page, I got rid of the float here and it worked fine.

```
div.rating-cancel, div.star-rating {
background:none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
cursor:pointer;
display:block;
/* float:left !important; */
}
```

Comment: Having just tried that myself, the stars now go vertical in halves :\ I'm using Chrome - but the solution obviously needs to work in all browsers anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Do you execute the javascript after onload fires?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//execute JS here
});
```

Comment: Yes, for this plugin this is included in the main file (see edit above), rather than on the page.

Answer (score 0):

5 star rating System using PHP and JQuery is used to rate different products or services on any web page in best user interactive way. User can rate content on scale of 1-5 star without reloading page. We just take an example of scan 1-5 otherwise by configuring JQuery scale can be change.
    In this Example we have used Raty.JS plugin for interactive stars.

**STEP-1
Create simple html file as shown below**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://testweb3.iecworld.com/jsdemo/js/lq_js_point/js/jquery.raty.min.js"></script>
    // Initialise Plugin
    $(document).ready(function(){
             $('.stars').raty({
                      score: function() {
                             return $(this).attr('data-score');
                      }
             });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<b>Star Rating Demo</b>
<div class=”stars”></div>
</body>
</html>
```

That’s it. Our stars will look something like
Star Rating Output

First of all we have created a simple HTML Document and have included Jquery and Raty JS.

Below code used to initialize Raty for star rating functionality.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.stars').raty({
                                  score: function() {
                                    return $(this).attr('data-score');
                                  }
});
    });
```

Star rating with read only value

```
$('.stars').raty({
                readOnly:  true
});
```

Number of Stars for rating
    $('.stars').raty({
    start:     2
    });

Onclick functionality
    $('.stars').raty({
    onClick: function(score) { alert('Your Score: ' + score); }
    });

Default cancel button

```
$('.stars').raty({
showCancel: true
});
```

Displaying Half Stars

```
$('.stars').raty({
showHalf:  true
});
```

User can also get value of selected stars and maintain value in database by using onclick event. Saty Stars are user friendly and supported by almost all browsers (Firefox, Google Chrome, Safari, Ipad, Iphone, Android Phone etc.).
[www.spjoshis.blogspot.com](http://spjoshis.blogspot.in/2015/01/rating-stars-with-raty.html)